# Taylor's Theorem and Mean Value Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

I've got the question

> By using Taylor's Theorem and the Constancy Theorem (essentially if
>   $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ then $f(x)$ is constant for all $x
>  \in [a,b]$) prove that
>
> $\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \dfrac{x}{2} + \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty
>  (-1)^{n-1} \dfrac{1}{2n}
>  \dfrac{(1-\frac{1}{2})(2-\frac{1}{2})...((n-1)-\frac{1}{2})}{(n-1)!}x^n$
>
> for $-1 < x \leq 1$

(I can't use the binomial theorem)

I've already shown it for $|x| < 1$ by using the taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ and differentiating the RHS within the radius of convergence $1$

However, I now need to show it for the end point $x = 1$, so I'm essentially trying to show

$\sqrt{2} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \dfrac{1}{2n} \dfrac{(1-\frac{1}{2})(2-\frac{1}{2})...((n-1)-\frac{1}{2})}{(n-1)!}$

But I'm not entirely sure how to go about it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have to see $1/(2n)$ is decreasing and the other factor has a finite partial sum.

Comment: @Yimin Thanks, I see that, however I'm still unsure how to proceed.

Comment: There is a Dirichlet criteria for determining convergence.http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dirichlet_criterion_(convergence_of_series)

Comment: @Yimmin Thanks again, I can see the sum converges - I just don't know how to prove it converges to $\sqrt{2} - \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: See Abel's theorem (second form): [http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=L25yJhCll78C&pg=PA453&lpg=PA453&dq=abel+theorem+power&source=bl&ots=ZVe0x13C8w&sig=uyJ4Rd7MauqIeheKqNx76nZb0uE&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=1SM6UbjoIcSSiAfi3IGoBg&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=abel%20theorem%20power&f=false]

Comment: @Taro Thanks, however I think I'm getting confused by something here. All this seems to let me do, is show that the sum converges. Is there a way I can use it to show it converges to the required $\sqrt{2} - \frac{3}{2}$? Thanks again.

Comment: @Noble: If the power series converges in $\lvert x \rvert <  1$ then the Abel's theorem states that
$$\sqrt{2} = \lim_{x \to 1-0} \big[ 1 + \dfrac{x}{2} + \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty
 (-1)^{n-1} \dfrac{1}{2n}
 \dfrac{(1-\frac{1}{2})(2-\frac{1}{2})...((n-1)-\frac{1}{2})}{(n-1)!}x^n \big] .$$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Not "in $\lvert x \rvert < 1$" but "at $x = 1$". Suggestion: How about write an answer by yourself putting these comments together and accept it?

Comment: @Noble do you mind explaining how you used the constancy theorem?

i've used taylors theorem to show the error term tends to zero for x in [0,1]  (the bit you are/were stuck on) but i dont see how we can get the other half of the interval through differentiating.

Comment: never mind bro i done it